# A question on the interval notation used in a Mechanism Design text book

Tags: notation

I'm working on understanding a textbook on Mechanism Design and I came across a part that I didn't quite understand, which is underlined in RED:

[image]

What does the underlined part refer to? I know it's an interval of some sort, but I'm clueless beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

[Interval Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_notation) is a method of specifying a chunk of the real numbers using the endpoint values and brackets of varying types to say what the nature of that end point is.  In this case, $[\theta_i,\overline {\theta_i} \cdot \overline {m_i}]$ means all the numbers between $\theta_i$ and $\overline {\theta_i} \cdot \overline {m_i}$, *including* both endpoints.

Comment: I know that, but what is the dot doing there between theta(i) and m(i)? And why is there a bar over theta?

Comment: The overline difference I don't know; there might be context in the rest of the passage.  I suspect the dot might be misplaced, the difference between `\overline {\theta_i} \cdot \overline {m_i}` and `\overline {\theta_{i\cdot}} \overline {m_i}`, which would be a common typo in automatic typesetters where you don't use tex commands directly.

Comment: What I got from another place in the book: $\overline {\theta_i}$ is the highest valuation of agent $i$, while $\underline {\theta_i}$ is the same agent's lowest valuation. So the lower bound makes sense. I'm still trying to figure out what the dot and the $\overline{m_i}$ are doing there.

Comment: Ahhh. Got it. This a major typo. The square brackets should be closed after $\overline {\theta_i}$ and there should be a period after that, as it ends the sentence. $\overline {m_i}$ begins a new sentence! This is awful..how am I going to get through the book??!

Comment: That's just bonkers.

Comment: You should add your own answer saying that and accept it, by the way, so we have a more permanent record of what's happened.  And you'll get some rep!

Comment: Ordinarily, @Joebevo, I counsel tolerance in cases like these: after all, texts are created and produced by fallible mortals, not divinities. But I agree with your frustration. If this is representative of the accuracy and reliability of the book, you are in for a rough ride. Good luck. And don’t forget to answer your own question, for just the reasons that Dan says.